# what is the fastest way to check whether string has uppercase letter in c#?

Tags: c#, string

My first implementation idea is to do simply:

```
bool hasUpperCase (string str) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
        if (char.IsUpper (str[i]))
            return true;                    
    }
    return false;
}
```

but maybe there is another faster way to do that ?

Comment: I would consider this "fast enough".

Comment: I think that is a good approach, you could use LINQ to do the work of the for loop, but the generated code would be equivalent. You could also test that the original string is not equal to the string converted to lower case, but I would expect that to be less performant as it would always require a full traverse of the string.

Comment: There might be some perfomance issues with using LINQ instead of a for-loop

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could reduce that to

```
bool HasUpperCase (string str) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c));
}
```

using LINQ.

Comment: e reduce again to:

 return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && password.Any(char.IsUpper);

Comment: so, if you have the string "12345", then HasUpperCase would still return true .. there is the need for checking of A-Z

Comment: @SmartPCInformatica You comment appears to be incorrect [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/shsyaG).

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer. This is a good solution but not the fastest as the questioner has asked. A non-LINQ solution would be quicker.

Answer (score 9):

[Cheating from here:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0e24579c-3c38-4a0d-aa5f-6732495c2c9b)

```
bool hasUpperCase (string str) {
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
     return false;

  return str != str.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: How efficient is this? You need to make a copy of the string just to do the comparison.

Comment: @Yuck: True! I'm not sure it's any more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

ok - time for the new truth!

This was a test for any upper case character in a string.

The string was guaranteed to not have any upper case character within the first 60K of characters.
(I created the string from random.org)

I prevented string substitution optimization in the compiler by randomizing which 64K character string was passed to the test function.

All timings were very strictly around the actual test, and did not include  function calling time.

I ran the test once, 10 times, and again for 10,000 times and averaged each set of the timings for each test.

I ran the test on a 64bit Win 7 with i3-2100 CPU @ 3.1 Ghz

Test Case 1:

```
   static bool testCaseOne(string str, out double ms)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c));
        ms = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
        return result;
    }
```

Resulting average time:

1. 1      X = 3.000 ms
2. 10     x = 0.860 ms
3. 10,000 x = 0.821 ms

Test Case 2:

```
    static bool testCaseTwo(string str, out double ms)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            ms = 0;
            return false;
        }
        result = Regex.IsMatch(str, "[A-Z]");

        ms = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;

        return result;
    }
```

Resulting average time:

1. 1      x = 2.000 ms
2. 10     x = 1.597 ms
3. 10,000 x = 1.603 ms

Test Case 3:

```
   static bool testCaseThree(string str, out double ms)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            ms = 0;
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(str[i]))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        ms = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
        return result;
    }
```

Resulting average time:

1. 1      x = 1.000 ms
2. 10     x = 0.357 ms
3. 10,000 x = 0.298 ms

Test Case 4:

```
    static bool testCaseFour(string str, out double ms)
    {
        bool result = false;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            ms = 0;
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {

            if (str[i] > 64 && str[i] < 91)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        ms = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Resulting average time:

1. 1      x = 0.000 ms
2. 10     x = 0.137 ms
3. 10,000 x = 0.184 ms

Interesting.

I hope this statisfies Mr. R. K. ;)

Comment: You do realize that case 1 & 4 are identical yet have different timing results?

Comment: must have copied the wrong code - that was so long ago, I don't remember what I did for case 4...Sorry!

Comment: Ok, since I was so badly beaten up by Mr. Koritnik (sob), I updated my answer above... ;)

Comment: Please use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do performance testing, `DateTime.Now` is a not effective.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool hasUpperCase(string str) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return false;
    return Regex.IsMatch(str, "[A-Z]");
}
```

*Disclaimer*: I am no Regex expert but I tested this with the strings `Testing, testinG, and tesTing,` which all evaluated to true. However, it also evaluated to true with the string `TESTING`, which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine to me, since you ask for performance, you can reduce the for loop from O(n) to O(n/2 + ~1) by adding the conditional checking from the reverse side.

Otherwise you can check two sub-sequent elements and increment the i by 2. Obviously you should check for i < str.Length for the second argument.

```
bool hasUpperCase (string str) {
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
     return false;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i= i + 2) {
    if (char.IsUpper (str[i]))
        return true;                    

    if ((i + 1) < str.Length && char.IsUpper (str[i+1]))
        return true;                    
}
return false;
```

}

IMHO, this tip may help to answer algorithm interview, doesn't get much performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string Upper_To_Lower(string text)
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(text[0]) == true) { text = text.Replace(text[0], char.ToLower(text[0])); return text; }

        return text;
    }

    public static string Lower_To_Upper(string text)
    {
        if (Char.IsLower(text[0]) == true) { text = text.Replace(text[0], char.ToUpper(text[0])); return text; }

        return text;
    }
```

Here i made 2 simple methods who check the first letter of any string and convert it from Upper to Lower and virse verca .... hope that will help you.