# Find text lower case or upper case

Tags: c#, regex

I need find text lower case or upper case  (using regex)
My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String s = "String : hello Hello HELLO hEllo ";
    String patern = @"(hello)";
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(patern);
    foreach (Match regex in myRegex.Matches(s)) {
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

It result :

```
hello
```

I need result

```
hello 
Hello 
HELLO 
hEllo
```

Can you help me?

Comment: usually this is done with a modifier, `i`. `"/hello/i"`

Comment: It not result . I don't know

Comment: Hope this might work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195270/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-check-whether-string-has-uppercase-letter-in-c

Answer (score 7):

Two ways:

```
 String patern = @"(?i)(hello)";
```

(?i) turns on case-insensitive comparison, and (?-i) restores the default case-sensitive comparison.

Or use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option when creating your regex object:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(patern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String patern = @"[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]";
```

Comment: Why is this better than a case-insensitivity flag?

Comment: It produces the same result for this particular scenario but this isn't as scalable as the other options, specifically if the search term is loaded dynamically rather than hard-coded statically, this approach would become more cumbersome than its worth.

Comment: It's also harder to read, unnecessarily complicated, and not as obvious in intent.

Comment: Yes I agree .. using the case Insensitive modifier is a better option if you are loading the Expression Dyanamically ..

Answer (score 0):

Pass RegexOptions.IgnoreCase when searching.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx